# How to search for whole lines

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, escaping

My intention is to determine if a whole line is present in a config file.
Here is an example:

ports.conf:

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Now I want to search for `NameVirtualHost *:80` but NOT for `#NameVirtualHost *:80`!

My first thought about this was, of course, to using grep. Like this:

`grep -F "NameVirtualHost *:80" ports.conf` That is giving me boths lines which is **not** what I want.
My second thought was to use regex like this: `grep -e "^NameVirtualHost \*:80" ports.conf`. But obviously now I have to treat with escaping special characters line `*`

This might be not a big deal but I want to pass individual search strings in and dont wanna bother with escaping strings as I am using my script.

So my question is:
**How do I escape special characters?** or **How can I achieve the same result with different tools?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` has an option `-x` which does exactly that:

```
-x, --line-regexp
          Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  (-x is specified by POSIX.)
```

So if you change your first command to `grep -Fx "NameVirtualHost *:80" ports.conf`, you get what you want.

Comment: nice usage of `-x`. but what if the line has leading blank (tab or spaces)? `(spaces...)NameVir....` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use printf escaping

```
printf '%q' 'NameVirtualHost *:80'
```

All together

```
grep -e "^`printf '%q' 'NameVirtualHost *:80'`$" test
```

Or

```
reg="NameVirtualHost *:80"
grep -e "^`printf '%q' "$reg"`$" test
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I can think of to keep your regexp simple is

```
grep -F "NameVirtualHost *:80" ports.conf | grep -v "^#\|^\/\/"
```

Comment: Is not helping me. If there is a commented line with `//` instead of `#` it is broken.

Comment: True, it will also not help if there is a space before the #, like ` # NameVirtualHost *:80` or if there in a comment after like `NameVirtualHost *:80 # comment`.